# .wrapAll except one inside a general wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper, wrapall

I have a group of generated divs width the same class which containts a header and a series of links. And for some reason a hidden header at the end.

They look something like this:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="Descr">List Header </label>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <label class="Descr2" style="display:none">Hidden List Header</label>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="Descr">List Header </label>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <a href="#">List item </a>
  <label class="Descr2" style="display:none">Hidden List Header</label>
</div>
```

And I got about three or four instances of these. Note that I can not change the code.

Now I want to wrap the achors in each parent inside a div to be able to add a jQuery scroll to it.

But using something like `.wrapAll` moves all the anchors in to one div and empties the others.

```js
jQuery('.wrapper a').wrapAll('<div class="content"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="Descr">List Header </label>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
    <a href="#">List item </a>
  </div>
  <label class="Descr2" style="display:none">Hidden List Header</label>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="Descr">List Header </label>

  <label class="Descr2" style="display:none">Hidden List Header</label>
</div>
```

Anyone got a clue how I can target the divs separately even though I only got general classes defined and make the acnhors stay inside their parents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() { 
    $('a', this).wrapAll('<div class="content"></div>');
});
```